# What will be a models.py should look like if I want one List to be written by only one User? [ User can have many list created]]

Tags: python, django, models

This is models.py:

```
class List(models.Model):
'''
This is the database table definition of List objects
'''
user=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
name=models.CharField(blank=False,max_length=255)
timestamp=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


class Meta:
    unique_together=['name','user']
    ordering = ['-timestamp']

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name
```

This should produce an error:

```
    user_obj1 = get_user_obj_by_name('Conor Lalor')
    user_obj2=get_user_obj_by_name()

    list_obj = List.objects.create(
        user=user_obj1,
        name='demo_list',
    )
    #with self.assertRaises(ValidationError):
    user_obj2.list_set.add(list_obj)
```

So my question is I how should I design my models.py to get desired error or Validation. I know these can be done be cleaning in forms.py but on this level how should I produce this simple error?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why should that raise an error? You explicitly say in the title that a user can have many lists.

Comment: Yes, but a list that have one user cannot be used another user. @DanielRoseman